# Calling geojson_list in R

Tags: r

I have a csv file with the locations of bicicle stations in four columns: "long", "lat", "nro_est", "nombre". I want to create a geojson fil from this csv file doing this:

```
as.json(geojson_list(estaciones, lat = 'lat', long = 'long'), pretty = TRUE)
```

the example from `?geojson_list` with data "states" is very similar but instead of creating points it creates polygons:

```
geojson_list(states[1:351,], geometry="polygon", group='group')
```

My problem with my adaption brings this error. It takes "nro_est" and "nombre" as coordinates and also it shows "long" as propertie. There is an NA that i dont understand. What am i doing wrong?

```
   "geometry": {
        "type": "Point",
        "coordinates": [-58.40436, -34.58819, 200, "NA"]
      },
   "properties": {
        "long": "-58.40436",
        "nro_est": "200",
        "nombre": "Austria y French"
      }
```

Comment: Can you edit your question with the output of `dput( head( estactiones ) ) `

Answer (score 0):

You can use `library(geojsonsf)` to convert a `data.frame` of lon/lat columns into geojson (with `POINT` geometries)

In the absence of your data I'm creating a dummy example to show you how it works.

```
library(geojsonsf)

estaciones <- data.frame(
  lat = rnorm(3)
  , long = rnorm(3)
  , nombre = sample(letters, size = 3)
  , nro_est = 1:3
)

geojson <- df_geojson( df = estaciones, lat = "lat", lon = "long" )

jsonify::pretty_json( geojson )
# {
#   "type": "FeatureCollection",
#   "features": [
#     {
#       "type": "Feature",
#       "properties": {
#         "nombre": "q",
#         "nro_est": 1
#       },
#       "geometry": {
#         "type": "Point",
#         "coordinates": [
#           0.6266271502100352,
#           -0.3347400043557775
#           ]
#       }
#     },
#     {
#       "type": "Feature",
#       "properties": {
#         "nombre": "a",
#         "nro_est": 2
#       },
#       "geometry": {
#         "type": "Point",
#         "coordinates": [
#           1.1169599023314834,
#           2.593126207650351
#           ]
#       }
#     },
#     {
#       "type": "Feature",
#       "properties": {
#         "nombre": "y",
#         "nro_est": 3
#       },
#       "geometry": {
#         "type": "Point",
#         "coordinates": [
#           0.18108997460569566,
#           0.4805016218807452
#           ]
#       }
#     }
#     ]
# }
```